# Is there a way to run a closure on RwLock drop?

Tags: rust, raii

I have a program that hides mutable state behind a RwLock. What I'd like to do is that when it's borrowed mutably (`RW_LOCK.write()`), on drop it should do something (namely, try to write to file, clean up the data behind the rwlock, etc.)

For example:

```
let DATA: RwLock<Data> = RwLock::new(Data { content: Default::default() } );

fn do_something() {
    let mut state = DATA.write().unwrap();

    state.change(5);
    // ...
    // Here, just before `state` goes out of scope (where it gets dropped and `RwLock` will allow 
    // other threads read/write access to `Data`, I would like for `RwLock` to auto-run `state.cleanup()`. 
}
```

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to reimplement `RwLock`?

Comment: Your question title mentions running a closure, but the body references running `state.cleanup()`. I assume the title needs an update? It would also be great if you could make your example complete enough to compile. The usage of `Lazy` also seems irrelevant to the question since the lock could be declared directly in the function in the context of this example.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I don't see any way of calling state.cleanup without a closure, but the main point is that somehow I should be able to do something with Data when a write lock gets dropped

Comment: Where do you see a closure affecting this? I think I understand what you want, but I don't think I follow where a closure would come into it, so I was hoping to clarify that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a wrapper type:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45ef2354e9e8c27f98a11ea58e086e97)

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut, Drop};
use std::sync::{RwLock, RwLockWriteGuard};

type CleanupClosure<'a> = Fn(&mut RwLockWriteGuard<'a, Data>);

struct Data {
    content: String,
}

impl Data {
    fn change(&mut self, num: i32) {
        println!("Changed to {}", num);
        self.content = num.to_string();
    }
}

struct RwLockWriteWrapper<'a, F: CleanupClosure<'a>>(RwLockWriteGuard<'a, Data>, F);

impl<'a, F: CleanupClosure<'a>> Deref for RwLockWriteWrapper<'a, F> {
    type Target = RwLockWriteGuard<'a, Data>;

    fn deref(&self) -> &RwLockWriteGuard<'a, Data> {
        &self.0
    }
}

impl<'a, F: CleanupClosure<'a>> DerefMut for RwLockWriteWrapper<'a, F> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut RwLockWriteGuard<'a, Data> {
        &mut self.0
    }
}

impl<'a, F: CleanupClosure<'a>> Drop for RwLockWriteWrapper<'a, F> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Cleaning up!");
        self.1(&mut self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data: RwLock<Data> = RwLock::new(Data {
        content: "Start".to_owned(),
    });
    do_something(&data);
    do_something(&data);
}

fn do_something(data: &RwLock<Data>) {
    // Write your own cleanup logic here
    let mut state = RwLockWriteWrapper(data.write().unwrap(), |state| {
        state.content = "Cleaned up".to_owned()
    });

    println!("do_something start: {}", state.content);
    state.change(5);

    println!("do_something after change: {}", state.content);
} // Automatically run cleanup here
```

It does require you to remember to wrap the type when you call `.write()` on it. You can wrap `RwLock` itself in another type that would return `RwLockWriteWrapper` to automate that as well.

This does become quite verbose, so I found [a crate that impls the deref trait for you](https://crates.io/crates/shrinkwraprs).

I am still not sure what closures you mentioned in the title meant.

Comment: Your `cleanup` method is hardcoded. OP wants to provide a closure instead, so one lock can do something different from another. For your example, `RwLockWriteWrapper` would take two parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper that implements `Drop`:

```
struct CleanOnDrop<D, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut D),
{
    data: D,
    cleanup: Option<F>,
}

impl<D, F> CleanOnDrop<D, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut D),
{
    pub fn new(data: D, cleanup: F) -> Self {
        Self { data, cleanup: Some(cleanup) }
    }
}

impl<D, F> Drop for CleanOnDrop<D, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut D)
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(mut cleanup) = self.cleanup.take() {
            cleanup(&mut self.data);
        }
    }
}
```

For convenience, you may want to implement `Deref` and `DerefMut` too, so that you can call methods on it directly:

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

impl<D, F> Deref for CleanOnDrop<D, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut D),
{
    type Target = D;
    fn deref(&self) -> &D {
        &self.data
    }
}

impl<D, F> DerefMut for CleanOnDrop<D, F>
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut D),
{
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut D {
        &mut self.data
    }
}
```

Use the wrapper like this:

```
let data = RwLock::new(CleanOnDrop::new(
    Data {
        content: Default::default(),
    },
    |state| {
        state.cleanup();
    },
));
```